# Iterating through list with count resetting on 0

Tags: python, algorithm

So I am working on algorithms and I have this section where I can't figure out.
Given a list of numbers, get the sum of consecutive values over 0 and add to new list.
Expected result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2] == [6, 3, 6]
```

I have tried:

```
    for i in splitlist2:   
    if i == 0:
        resultlist.append((count2))
        count2 = 0
    else:
        count2 += i
```

Produces [6, 3]. I don't get why the last value is not appearing. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Is the answer to the example input you provided `[3, 3, 6]` or `[6,3,6]`?

Comment: I apologize, i have edited the question.

Comment: sure, no problem :D

Comment: Where do you get `count2`?

Comment: count2 = 0, its a counter variable i set up early in the script.

Comment: The last value doesn't appear, because you only add a value when you encounter a zero. After the loop, you should add one extra `resultlist.append(count2)`. However, note that if there are two zeroes consecutive, such as `[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]`, then your code produces an extra zero in the result: `[6, 0, 3]`. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def custom_sum(arr): 
    if not arr: return [] 
    res = [0] 
    for i, el in enumerate(arr): 
        if el == 0: 
            if i != len(arr)-1: 
                res.append(0) 
        else:
            res[-1] += el 
    return res
```

A quick test:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2]
custom_sum(arr)
[6, 3, 6]
```

The general algorithm:

1. If the input array is empty return empty array
2. Otherwise initialize a result array with a 0
3. Loop over the elements of the input array:
4. If the element is 0, check whether it's the last element. If it's the last element of the input array, ignore. Otherwise, add a zero to the result array for a new partition.
5. If the element is not zero, add its value to the last value in result array.

Comment: Is this the expected output for this list `print(custom_sum([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]))` Get `[0, 0, 1, 0, 1]`

Comment: I am not sure, since OP was not specific about such edge cases.

Comment: Well, it'll be nicer to ask OP confirm and able to handle possibly `edge` cases.

Comment: It is the outcome, however for my situation, the first number will always be > 0 and that consecutive 0's would be an error from a previous function call.

Comment: Just curious, does anyone know why the function I used excluded the last split of consecutive numbers?

Comment: Yes, @DayLy you add `count2` to the list, if and only if you encounter a zero. If there is no zero at the end of your list, you miss adding the sum of the last partition. To mitigate that, you could add a condition after you have looped over all elements such that if `count2` is greater than 0, add it to the result. I hope that makes sense because I haven't seen the full code of yours.

Comment: Gave me a good idea for my situation, really appreciate it. As you said, I added an if statement after the for loop and got what i needed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import groupby

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2]
ans = []
return [sum(list(v)) for k,v in groupby(list1, key = lambda x: x != 0) if k != 0]
```

Output :

```
[6,3,6]
```

Comment: This should be accepted as the `right` answer.  However, it's still can be made simpler ...

Comment: yes Daniel Hao .

Comment: Suggestion to this line - `return [sum(list(v)) for k, v in ... ]` instead.